# Django Heroku app doesn't run after successful deploy

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

After a successful deploy of a Django project I've made a few attempts to run this app on a dyno, however, it drops some errors. It's running with no issues locally tho.

```
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
2018-10-06T19:08:44.455276+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user tamerlanium@gmail.com
2018-10-06T19:08:51.519039+00:00 heroku[run.5633]: State changed from starting to up
2018-10-06T19:08:51.515345+00:00 heroku[run.5633]: Awaiting client
2018-10-06T19:08:51.578011+00:00 heroku[run.5633]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2018-10-06T19:08:57.062762+00:00 heroku[run.5633]: State changed from up to complete
2018-10-06T19:08:57.046603+00:00 heroku[run.5633]: Process exited with status 1
2018-10-06T19:09:21.974583+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tarlansblog.herokuapp.com request_id=b037e1d6-8a68-4992-8c4e-21462664ff0e fwd="176.107.221.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-06T19:09:23.424575+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tarlansblog.herokuapp.com request_id=05d085e7-cf21-47a8-9752-1da68c0fa940 fwd="176.107.221.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-06T19:10:05.844413+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tarlansblog.herokuapp.com request_id=9c64e68d-ba6c-422e-983c-9f9b30aac866 fwd="176.107.221.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-06T19:10:06.995437+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tarlansblog.herokuapp.com request_id=9c9f6e8e-0233-4b3f-96c6-71882e4e17fe fwd="176.107.221.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-06T19:14:25.639377+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user tamerlanium@gmail.com
```

Comment: Did you run ```pip freeze > requirements.txt``` and add it to your git commit?

Comment: Yeah, that file contains some appeared dependencies. I did all steps along this post:  https://www.codementor.io/jamesezechukwu/how-to-deploy-django-app-on-heroku-dtsee04d4.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I would say that you have a problem with your static files. When Heroku tries to get them, you have a 503 error status.
Maybe you should try to review how you collect your statics files in your django project. This link should help you to resolve this problem:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Julien I've just added some raws which weren't in settings.py before then deployed it with changes, but it hasn't helped so far.

Comment: It will be difficult for me to give you more information without code. Did you check if your STATIC_ROOT targets correctly the directory where you collected your static files?

Comment: I defined it in such a way. I don't know how and where to check that out.

`PROJECT_ROOT   =   os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT  =   os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra lookup directories for collectstatic to find static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

#  Add configuration for static files storage using whitenoise
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

Comment: OK, thanks. So if I understand well, your staticfiles folder where you collect all your static is in your project folder, where you have your settings.py, right? I also don't understand your STATICFILES_DIRS. All your statics files are in your project folder called 'static' folder?

Comment: Thank you mate :) The project has only one static folder which contains a css file. You can see it on a tree https://codeshare.io/2prb7V. There's also deployed code on GitHub: https://github.com/organicnz/tarlansblog.git

Comment: No problem :). Try to replace `PROJECT_ROOT   =   os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__))` by `PROJECT_ROOT   =   os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`. I think it will get correctly your project root by this way